# How to register a global key listener in electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm trying to listen to keystrokes on a given key even if the window isn't focused. I'm using electron.

[EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) only works when the windows is focused and electron's [globalShortcuts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut#globalshortcutregisteraccelerator-callback) overrides the keys rather than listening to them.

**Q:** Is there a way to do this without writting C modules targetting each platform?

An example of an electron app doing this is Discord with their user customisable keybinds.

Comment: what is the issue in using globalshortcuts? just to know

Comment: It actually overrides the key input globally, so if you register a listener for `a`, the user won't be able to type `a` in any other app while our app is open.